# Running java with --add-reads doesn't recognize a module even though it appears when running with --list-modules

Tags: java, java-module

Given two modules `m1` and `m2` on the module path:

```
java -version
openjdk version "11.0.2" 2019-01-15

java -p M2/bin:M1/bin --list-modules
...
m1 <path>M1/bin/
m2 <path>M2/bin/
```

When running module `m2`, and specifying `--add-reads` from `m2` to `m1`:

```
java -p M2/bin:M1/bin --add-reads m2=m1 -m m2/p2.C2
WARNING: Unknown module: m1 specified to --add-reads
...
```

Java cannot see the module `m1`, even though when using `--list-modules` it is clearly visible.

How to make `--add-reads` recognize the module?

Answer (score 6):

Unlike `requires` in `module-info.java`, `--add-reads` will not add the module to the module graph, even though [the documentation](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/261) for `--add-reads` says: `This is, essentially, a command-line form of a requires clause in a module declaration`. Turns out that the actual equivalent is `--add-modules` combined with `--add-reads`:

```
java -p M2/bin:M1/bin --add-modules m1 --add-reads m2=m1 -m m2/p2.C2
```